# Moving webapps directory out of Jetty Home

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jetty, scalability

i want to move the webapps directory out of the Jetty Home Directory. How do i do that ..
And i want to use jetty as a servlet container only, i won't even serve html files with jetty, how do i do that .(Since jetty claims that all the features are pluggable, i just want to un plug the unwanted things in jetty, using it plainly as a servlet container).

Comment: Why do you want to unplug the things you don't need? It's going to create a lot more work for you, for not much gain. It doesn't sound like your familiar enough with the Jetty internals to justify going down that path.

Comment: From the jetty's website , unplugging unwanted things - thats the beauty of Jetty. I just want to make it light weight, so that if the servlet request grows,jetty won't took more memory. I just want to reduce the Jetty's System memory Usage. 
Jetty Version :8.0.4.v20111024